# Resgatar chave de dicionário com soma máxima de valor respectivo

Tags: python, dicionário

Tenho o seguinte dicionário:

```
dic = {'bsx_8612': [23, 567, 632], 'asd_6375': [654, 12, 962], 'asd_2498': [56, 12, 574], 'bsx_9344': [96, 1022, 324]}
```

Quero resgatar a chave cujo valor tem a maior soma de seus elementos. Como estou fazendo:

```
chaves, valores = [], []
for item in dic:
    valores.append(sum(dic.get(item)))
    chaves.append(item)

chave = chaves[valores.index(max(valores))]
print(chave)
>>> asd_6375
```

Existe uma maneira mais prática de fazer essa operação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dic = {'bsx_8612': [23, 567, 632], 'asd_6375': [654, 12, 962], 'asd_2498': [56, 12, 574], 'bsx_9344': [96, 1022, 324]}

print max(dic.iteritems(), key = lambda (k, v): sum(v))[0]

# Python 3
print(max(dic.items(), key = lambda t: sum(t[1]))[0])
```

Nas funções `sort`, `sorted`, `max`, `min`, … você pode passar o parâmetro `key = …` pra usar uma função dos seus dados como chave de comparação/ordenação.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/7oBo9O).